# проблема переноса сайта с Xampp на OpenServer

Tags: php, openserver, xampp

Добрый день! Перенес сайт с xampp на openserver  загрузилась только главная страница когда перехожу по ссылкам, то в строке написан верный путь также в ссылках написаны все пути верно, страница остается та же, главная, а путь меняется.
Базу переносил с помощью экспорта и импорта.
[image: Главная страница]

[image: Это пишет при переходе на ссылку, страница остается та же]

Comment: Настройка для веб сервера правильно перенесли? Там код прописывается, чтобы ЧПУ работали. Я надеюсь вы там и там Апач используете? Если да, и настройки для ЧПУ в .htaccess в корне, то может запрещено использовать .htaccess?

Comment: Я использую nginx, пожем посоветуете где можно прочитать об этом? я не нашел про перенос на другой локальный сервер

Comment: Если используете только nginx без апача за ним, то надо настройки ЧПУ перенести из апача в nginx. Читать надо настройки того и другого. Приведите свой конфиг для сайта на апаче, посмотрим что можно сделать.